# CGAffineTransformMakeScale and Rotation at once?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-graphics

I want to apply scale and rotation at once.Problem is when i do this rotation is correct but scale  reduce. I test scale and rotate separately and it working perfectly. Following is my code

```
CGAffineTransform transformScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale( tmp.size, tmp.size);
CGAffineTransform transformRotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat)tmp.rotation);
[iview setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(transformScale, transformRotate)];
```

Comment: NSLog `temp.size`.  I'll bet it's less than `1.0f`, which would shrink your object.

Comment: What does the NSLog look like, and what does it print?